# .NET Regex for "not this string"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm a regex newbie and need a single expression that:

matches the "an" and the "AN" but not the "and" or "AND" and matches the "o" and the "O" but not the "or" or "OR" in this predicate:

1and(2or3)AND(4OR5)an(6o7)AN(8O9)

Basically I can't figure out how to convert the expression:

```
var myRegEx = Regex("[0-9 ()]|AND|OR")
```

into a "everything but", case insensitive expression.

Can't use the regex word boundaries feature because the predicate isn't required to have spaces.

> (Added after two answers were already
>   provided): I also need to know the
>   index of the match, which is why I'm
>   assuming I need to use the
>   Regex.Match() method.

Thanks!

Here's what I ended up with:

```
  private bool mValidateCharacters()
  {
     const string legalsPattern = @"[\d ()]|AND|OR";
     const string splitPattern = "(" + legalsPattern + ")";
     int position = 0;
     string[] tokens = Regex.Split(txtTemplate.Text, splitPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     // Array contains every legal operator/symbol found in the entry field
     // and every substring preceeding, surrounded by, or following those operators/symbols
     foreach (string token in tokens)
     {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
           continue;
        }

        // Determine if the token is a legal operator/symbol or a syntax error
        Match match = Regex.Match(token, legalsPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.ToString()))
        {
           const string reminder =
              "Please use only the following in the template:" +
              "\n\tRow numbers from the terms table" +
              "\n\tSpaces" +
              "\n\tThese characters: ( )" +
              "\n\tThese words: AND OR";
           UserMsg.Tell("Illegal template entry '" + token + "'at position: " + position + "\n\n" + reminder, UserMsg.EMsgType.Error);
           txtTemplate.Focus();
           txtTemplate.Select(position, token.Length);
           return false;
        }

        position += token.Length;
     }

     return true;
  }
```

Comment: *the "an" and the "AN" but not the "and" or "AND" and matches the "o" and the "O" but not the "or" or "OR"* - has to be one of the best sentence fragments I've ever read on SO.

Comment: Thanks...I had to work really hard to come up with that :)

Comment: You want the opposite of this right?
[0-9 ()]|AND|OR|and|or

Comment: May I ask, do you think C# regex's are different from .NET regexes, or is this just a manner of speaking?

Comment: You are trying to match everything except 0-9, space, parenthisis, AND, OR? Is that right?

Comment: You write that you 'need a single expression that: ...' Why do you need to do this with a single regular expression? Do you really *need* that or would you accept alternative solutions?

Comment: I actually didn't give any thought to whether or not C# has its own regex engine. I rather doubt it but am programming in C# so that's the only solution I need.

Comment: Mark - I'm sure I could use a state machine to manually parse my way through an expression. As I've started using Regex, I'm finding most of the time I can replace whole methods with a single line. I guess I assumed (naively?) the current problem would be one of those cases.

Comment: Whoops - sorry SAM, missed your comment. You are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Randal Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz)'s rule: Use capturing in `Regex.Match` when you know what you want to keep, and use `Regex.Split` when you know what you want to throw away.

You wrote you want “everything but,” so

```
var input = "1and(2or3)AND(4OR5)an(6o7)AN(8O9)";
foreach (var s in Regex.Split(input, @"[\d()]|AND|OR", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
  if (s.Length > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", s);
```

Output:

```
[an]
[o]
[AN]
[O]
```

To get the offsets, save the separators by enclosing the regular expression in parentheses:

```
var input = "1and(2or3)AND(4OR5)an(6o7)AN(8O9)";
string pattern = @"([\d()]|AND|OR)";
int offset = 0;
foreach (var s in Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
  if (s.ToLower() == "an" || s.ToLower() == "o")
    Console.WriteLine("Found [{0}] at offset {1}", s, offset);
  offset += s.Length;
}
```

Output:

```
Found [an] at offset 19
Found [o] at offset 23
Found [AN] at offset 26
Found [O] at offset 30
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit in the stated requirements, because when I said "a single expression that matches..." I used the term "matches" because I need the index of the point of interest (e.g. usage of "AN") and Regex.Match() provides that (that is, it would if I could figure out how to structure the expression!). If no one can provide a solution that includes index, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks gbacon! For anyone interested, I've posted the method I was writing above.